# Nested dynamic menu with knpmenubundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I've built a menu using knpmenubundle, it's working really well and pulling the navigation dynamically from the database. However the client now wants to add a submenu to it. I've written a controller which will find child pages, however I can't see how I can attach them to the subnavigation under the correct parent. At the moment all it does it attach a copy of the current element to itself as a child node.

**Here is the menu builder:**

```
 $sector = $options['sector'];
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $navItems = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('acmeStyleGuideBundle:pageSector')
    ->findBySectorJoinedToUrl($sector);
    if (!$navItems) throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find any matching pages');
    $menu = $factory->createItem('root');
    foreach ($navItems as $nav)
    {
        // Doesn't have any parents, This is a top level
        $parent = $menu->addChild($nav->getPageName(), array(
            'route' => 'acme_style_guide_pages_show',
            'routeParameters' => array(
                'sector' => $sector,
                'pageUrl' => $nav->getPageUrl()
            )
        ));
        $parent->addChild($nav->getPageName(), array(
            'route' => 'acme_style_guide_pages_show_sub',
            'routeParameters' => array(
                'sector' => $sector,
                'pageParent' => $nav->getPageName(),
                'pageUrl' => $nav->getPageUrl()
            ))
        );
    }
```

**Here is the controller for the parent element:**

```
 // Render pages from database
public function showAction($sector, $pageUrl)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pages = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('acmeStyleGuideBundle:PageContent')
    ->findByUrlJoinedToSector($sector, $pageUrl);

    if (!$pages) throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find any matching pages');
    return $this->render(
        'acmeStyleGuideBundle:Page:pages.html.twig', 
        array(
            'Pages' => $pages,
            'sector' => $sector
        )
    );
}
```

**and here is the controller for the child element:**

```
// Render sub pages from database
public function showSubAction($sector, $pageParent, $pageUrl)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pages = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('acmeStyleGuideBundle:PageContent')
    ->findByUrlJoinedToSectorAndParent($sector, $pageParent, $pageUrl);

    if (!$pages) throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find any matching pages');
    return $this->render(
        'acmeStyleGuideBundle:Page:pages.html.twig', 
        array(
            'Pages' => $pages,
            'sector' => $sector
        )
    );
}
```

Both of these controllers pull information from the database using a custom repository class.

**Here is the custom repository code:**

```
public function findByUrlJoinedToSector($sector, $pageUrl)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT p, s FROM acmeStyleGuideBundle:PageContent p
            JOIN p.pageSector s
            LEFT JOIN p.pageTypes t
            WHERE p.pageUrl = :url
            AND s.sectorName = :sector
            AND t.typeName != :type'
        )
        ->setParameter('url', $pageUrl)
        ->setParameter('sector', $sector)
        ->setParameter('type', 'Section Headers');

    try {
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public function findByUrlJoinedToSectorAndParent($sector, $pageParent, $pageUrl)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT p, s, c FROM acmeStyleGuideBundle:PageContent p
            JOIN p.pageSector s
            LEFT JOIN p.pageTypes t
            LEFT JOIN p.PageParent c
            WHERE p.pageUrl = :url
            AND s.sectorName = :sector
            AND c.pageUrl = :parent
            AND t.typeName != :type'
        )
        ->setParameter('url', $pageUrl)
        ->setParameter('sector', $sector)
        ->setParameter('parent', $pageParent)
        ->setParameter('type', 'Section Headers');

    try {
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It could be just a *Monday morning* issue, so I'll keep trying to work it out myself, if I do I will post it here as an answer.

**Additional info**

Updated builder
  // find all items with parents. Then attach the found item to its parent.
            $subNavItems = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('acmeStyleGuideBundle:pageSector')
            ->findSubNav($sector, $nav->getPageParent());

```
        // loop over them and add a link for each one:
        foreach ($subNavItems as $child) {
            if ($child->getPageParent() != NULL) {
                $parent->addChild($child->getPageName(), array(
                    'route' => 'acme_style_guide_pages_show_sub',
                    'routeParameters' => array(
                        'sector' => $sector,
                        'pageParent' => $child->getPageName(),
                        'pageUrl' => $child->getPageUrl()
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

**It's outputting:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="link">Target Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Child</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Whereas I need it to output:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="link">Target Item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">Child</a></li>
</ul>
```

**This is the schema for the PageContent table**

```
<database name="styleguide">
        <!-- Table PageContent -->
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">1</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">2</column>
            <column name="pageName">Text Elements</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">text-elements</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">2</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">2</column>
            <column name="pageName">Buttons</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">buttons</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">3</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">2</column>
            <column name="pageName">Forms</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">forms</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">4</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">2</column>
            <column name="pageName">Lists</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">lists</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">5</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">2</column>
            <column name="pageName">Tables</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">tables</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">6</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">2</column>
            <column name="pageName">Search Box</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">search-box</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">7</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">2</column>
            <column name="pageName">Pods</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">pods</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">8</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">3</column>
            <column name="pageName">Business</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">business</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">9</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">3</column>
            <column name="pageName">Residential</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">residential</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">NULL</column>
        </table>
        <table name="PageContent">
            <column name="id">10</column>
            <column name="pageTypesId">1</column>
            <column name="pageName">Paragraphs</column>
            <column name="pageUrl">paragraphs</column>
            <column name="richText">&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.&lt;/p&gt;</column>
            <column name="PageParent">1</column>
        </table>
    </database>
```

Comment: Either your `query` or your database has a mistake in it. Your code is correct. I guess the `child` item is linked to the wrong parent in the database.

Comment: i think it may be because the of the way my data is laid out (added XML of table schema to question). Instead of the parents containing an array of children in a one-to-many relationship. I tried to do it with the child containing a reference to it's parent in a one-to-one relationship. This seemed like the most sensible way to do it but it looks like it might be causing problems. Do you think it would be easy to code around this or should I change my db structure?

Comment: You find many [examples in the official doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over all `subElements` and render a navigation link for each:

```
foreach ($navItems as $nav)
{
    // Doesn't have any parents, This is a top level
    $parent = $menu->addChild($nav->getPageName(), array(
        'route' => 'acme_style_guide_pages_show',
        'routeParameters' => array(
            'sector' => $sector,
            'pageUrl' => $nav->getPageUrl()
        )
    ));

    // find all sub-items:
    $subNavItems = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('acmeStyleGuideBundle:pageSector')
    ->findByUrlJoinedToSectorAndParent($sector, $parent, /* $pageUrl */);

    // loop over them and add a link for each one:
    foreach ($subNavItems as $child) {
        $parent->addChild($child->getPageName(), array(
            'route' => 'acme_style_guide_pages_show_sub',
            'routeParameters' => array(
                'sector' => $sector,
                'pageParent' => $child->getPageName(),
                'pageUrl' => $child->getPageUrl()
            ))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked really well. I had to make a custom repository method for it as the 'findByUrlJoinedToSectorAndParent()' one wasn't really approriate. Thanks! :)

Comment: you just need to remember that child elements are nothing different than the root element. If you keep that in mind `knpMenus` are really easy to create.

Comment: Actually. I've just noticed that it's still not QUITE working the way I expected. It is only outputting items which have parents now but it's still putting copies of the item underneath itself. I've put the new output in my question.

Comment: Can you update your question to add output `html` and you current `menu builder`?

Comment: You need to add the info to your question, not my answer. Also please provide twig template code.

Comment: Whoops! That was an accident. Sorry. Done now :) Not sure what to put for the twig code, all I have in my templtes is the render menu command.